# How can I stop maven from running TEST twice?

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a big project with around 5000 test cases. When running `mvn clean install` it will run the `test` goal twice (one as part of the install and the second time as part of the `surefire` plugin).

Why it needs to run the `test` for the second time? And is there away to force `surefire` to use the `test` goal results instead of re-invoking it's own?
I see it as a waste of time and machine resource, especially recently the second round of running the `test` caused a `PermGen` build error and no matter how much heap I pump into maven runner it still dies in the second testing round.

This is my surefire pluging configuration:

```
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <executions>
       <execution>
         <id>default-test</id>
         <phase>test</phase>
         <goals>
             <goal>test</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <parallel>classes</parallel>
            <threadCount>3</threadCount>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Is there a way to tweak the plugin to better handle machine resources?

Here is the full default maven profile  which gets executed:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Build-Number>${build.number}</Build-Number>
                        <Job-Name>${job.name}</Job-Name>
                        <Build-Url>${build.url}</Build-Url>
                        <Git-Commit>${git.commit}</Git-Commit>
                        <Git-Branch>${git.branch}</Git-Branch>
                        <Timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</Timestamp>
                        <StyleGuide-Version>${styleguide.version}</StyleGuide-Version>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <warName>pss</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.cj.jshintmojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jshint-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>lint</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <options>maxparams:5,camelcase,eqeqeq,forin,immed,latedef,noarg,noempty,nonew,expr</options>
                <directories>
                    <directory>src/main/webapp/js/page</directory>
                </directories>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>src/main/webapp/js/page/marketingPreferences.js</exclude>
                    <exclude>src/main/webapp/js/page/changeCarParkingDetails.js</exclude>
                    <exclude>src/main/webapp/js/page/angularjs-app.js</exclude>
                    <exclude>src/main/webapp/js/page/content-cover.js</exclude>
                    <exclude>src/main/webapp/js/page/amendmentConfirm.js</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.lesscss</groupId>
            <artifactId>lesscss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>bingleless</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/app-resources/</sourceDirectory>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/app-resources/</outputDirectory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**\/policy-self-service\/**\/*pss-sg.less</include>
                        </includes>
                        <compress>true</compress>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compress</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.min.js</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.min.css</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/style-guide/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/generated/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/app-resources/common/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/app-resources/bower_components/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/app-resources/policy-self-service/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
                <jswarn>false</jswarn>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <logViolationsToConsole>true</logViolationsToConsole>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>classes</parallel>
                <threadCount>3</threadCount>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-report-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report-only</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Do you tried to remove the executions part?

Comment: Please add (trimmed) the output of `mvn clean install`, especially the lines starting with `[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin` - that should help track when and how many times the plugin is executed.

Comment: It only runs once, do you have other plugins?

Comment: @Zelldon Yes I tried removing the execution part, still calling it twice.

Comment: @ravthiru The only other plugin is `maven-surefire-report-plugin`. You can see the full maven <build> above.

Comment: @AdamMichalik Could you please explain what do you mean by 'adding trimmed'? Can you suggest a revised configuration? Thanks.

Comment: Trimmed output means a short copy of your log when you run mvn clean install. It helps to see when the maven test is invoked

Answer (score 8):

I think the `<execution>` in your `pom.xml` causes the 2nd test run. Maven sees it as another goal to execute in addition to the default goal in the test phase.

Since `maven-surefire-plugin` is a plugin used by default in Maven for test phase, you only need to provide the `<configuration>` part outside of `<execution>`. Modify your `pom.xml` as below

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <parallel>classes</parallel>
        <threadCount>3</threadCount>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: This is correct, cause maven-surefire-plugin is by default already bound to the life cycle. Best is to give configuration via pluginManagement instead of in build..

Comment: @Rocherlee Tried that, didn't work either. Still calling TESTS twice.

Comment: @DhafirNz Did you ever find the solution?

Comment: A good way of finding out what is going on is to use: mvn help:effective-pom

Answer (score 0):

If in your pom both cobertura and surefire plugin are there tests will execute twice. To avoid that add execution phase as none in cobertura plugin like mentioned below:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found that:
because of using `rerunFailingTestsCount` of `maven-surefire-plugin`, so in case of there is a failed test, it will be run again.

By the way:
I am against trying to re-run flaky test multiple times till success, instead we can resolve the root cause of it.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        ...
        <!-- Workaround to make builds more stable while having flaky tests -->
        <rerunFailingTestsCount>1</rerunFailingTestsCount>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by only running mvn surefire-report:report -DskipTests.
it ran the whole soapui project- in my soapuimaven plugin configuration and then generated the surefire html report.